# AdonisJs: Using Hashids

Tags: node.js, uuid, adonis.js, hashids

Had already someone used Hashids in AdonisJs?

Being more specific, in a Model, to return a property **hashid** in an object

I'm working on a migration from Laravel to Adonis.
In Laravel, it's possible just with a couple of code lines in each Model, like this:

```
use Hashids;

class Menu extends Model
{
    use \OwenIt\Auditing\Auditable;

    protected $appends = ['hashid'];

    public function getHashidAttribute()
    {
        return Hashids::encode($this->attributes['id']);
    }
}
```

I installed this NPM package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/adonis-hashids, and I tried to figure out how to use like the Laravel way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd used Computed Properties (https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/database-getters-setters#_computed_properties)

```
class Menu extends Model {
  static get computed () {
    return ['hashids']
  }
  getHashids({ id }) {
    return Hashids.encode(id)
  }
}
```